# Trying to run Kubedoom on Cloud Run as a service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy a service on Cloud Run with the image of this git:

https://github.com/storax/kubedoom/blob/master/README.md

I was able to run with no issues on GKE and helm but I am having trouble deploying on Cloud Run.

Here is my YAML

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kubedoom-kubedoom-chart
  namespace: 'projectnumber'
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kubedoom-chart
    spec:
      containers:
        #      - env:
        # - name: NAMESPACE
        #  value: nginx
        image: gcr.io/alealferez-project-1/kubedoom:v5
        name: kubedoom-chart
          # ports:
          # - containerPort: 5900
          #name: http1
          #protocol: TCP
          #hostPort: 5900
          #listenAddress: "127.0.0.1"
```

This was my original yaml from GKE:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "2"
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: kubedoom
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: kubedoom
  creationTimestamp: "2023-02-28T17:56:47Z"
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kubedoom
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kubedoom-chart
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.16.0
    helm.sh/chart: kubedoom-chart-0.1.0
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:meta.helm.sh/release-name: {}
          f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/version: {}
          f:helm.sh/chart: {}
      f:spec:
        f:progressDeadlineSeconds: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
        f:selector: {}
        f:strategy:
          f:rollingUpdate:
            .: {}
            f:maxSurge: {}
            f:maxUnavailable: {}
          f:type: {}
        f:template:
          f:metadata:
            f:labels:
              .: {}
              f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
              f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
          f:spec:
            f:containers:
              k:{"name":"kubedoom-chart"}:
                .: {}
                f:image: {}
                f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:ports:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"containerPort":5900,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:containerPort: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:protocol: {}
                f:resources:
                  .: {}
                  f:limits:
                    .: {}
                    f:cpu: {}
                    f:memory: {}
                  f:requests:
                    .: {}
                    f:cpu: {}
                    f:memory: {}
                f:securityContext: {}
                f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
            f:dnsPolicy: {}
            f:restartPolicy: {}
            f:schedulerName: {}
            f:securityContext: {}
            f:serviceAccount: {}
            f:serviceAccountName: {}
            f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
    manager: helm
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-02-28T17:56:47Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        f:template:
          f:spec:
            f:containers:
              k:{"name":"kubedoom-chart"}:
                f:env:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"name":"NAMESPACE"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
    manager: GoogleCloudConsole
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-02-28T18:05:13Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: {}
      f:status:
        f:availableReplicas: {}
        f:conditions:
          .: {}
          k:{"type":"Available"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"Progressing"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
        f:observedGeneration: {}
        f:readyReplicas: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:updatedReplicas: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    subresource: status
    time: "2023-02-28T18:06:39Z"
  name: kubedoom-kubedoom-chart
  namespace: kubedoom
  resourceVersion: "100217215"
  uid: e7e0870a-5782-4926-8aac-eb0d2105f720
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: kubedoom
      app.kubernetes.io/name: kubedoom-chart
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: kubedoom
        app.kubernetes.io/name: kubedoom-chart
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: NAMESPACE
          value: nginx
        image: ghcr.io/storax/kubedoom:0.6.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: kubedoom-chart
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5900
          name: vnc
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 500Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 500Mi
        securityContext: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
```

I keep getting the classic error:

```
Revision 'kubedoom-kubedoom-chart-ltzkf' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable
```

I expect the service to start serving

Comment: Are you sure that container is running on port `8080`? From the docs it says by default it uses the port `5900` and in fact you use that port in your k8s version.

Comment: Uncomment the container port, it should be the issue

Comment: you can choose what port to run it in on Cloud Run, so I chose 5900 to match that of the container. And I have tried uncommenting the port and still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and the issue is expected.

This will not work because this tool is trying to connect to a K8s cluster.

1. This container when starting is looking for `localhost:8080` why? In the logs it says:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
The following command failed: "[kubectl get pods -A -o go-template --template={{range .items}}{{.metadata.namespace}}/{{.metadata.name}} {{end}}]"
```

It's because the container is trying to connect to the K8s API. And this is confirmed in the source code:

```golang
func (m podmode) getEntities() []string {
    var args []string
    if namespace, exists := os.LookupEnv("NAMESPACE"); exists {
        args = []string{"kubectl", "get", "pods", "--namespace", namespace, "-o", "go-template", "--template={{range .items}}{{.metadata.namespace}}/{{.metadata.name}} {{end}}"}
    } else {
        args = []string{"kubectl", "get", "pods", "-A", "-o", "go-template", "--template={{range .items}}{{.metadata.namespace}}/{{.metadata.name}} {{end}}"}
    }
    output := outputCmd(args)
    outputstr := strings.TrimSpace(output)
    pods := strings.Split(outputstr, " ")
    return pods
}
```

The solution would be that you provide the K8s config of the cluster you're interested to connect and build a container in any case.

Anyway I don't think this will work even doing this because the exposed PORT which is `5900` expects a VNC connection using only TCP while Cloud Run always expects HTTP connections. Maybe this can be solved but adds some overhead.

My advice for you is to learn how to debug using the logs and understand what you're doing. Not always moving things from one technology to another is straightforward even if those are "similar."